# can spring state machine be triggered from an external entity

Tags: spring-statemachine

we have a project where SSM seems like a viable option. the question i have is whether SSM can be triggered from an external source. the documentation talks about 'local' vs 'external' transitions but, to me, this is talking about a hierarchical state machine; you have multiple, orthogonal state 'flows' & one can affect the other.

is it possible to trigger 'actions' via an external entity; eg. a messaging system that sends a messages inducing a state change?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is that you want to know if it is possible to **send events/messages from another application/process directly to the state machine** without any further technology/component, am I right?

**In this case the answer would be no, you cannot.** To the best of my knowledge, [Spring state machine](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) does not provide any client or server components out of the box which would enable sending events directly from another process.

But of course you can make your state machine program a client which connects to a message broker, for example. It could then receive messages via the broker from any application and handle them accordingly e.g. by sending an event to the state machine and returning a message.

Comment: thank you for your reply, this was my conclusion as well